# Classic ASP page stops when DB operation takes long

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have an ASP page from where I call a SQL Stored Proc. This SP is doing some heavy database operations thus takes time sometimes. It could take more than 3 minutes at times. It works fine sometimes but sometimes the ASP gets stuck. I.e. the page just stops, it doesnt do anything. Neither does it say that the DB operation was successful nor would it throw an error message.

Why does this happen? What property should I set on my page so that it would wait for the database response?

Hello Again,

I have more information on the problem I am facing. After analyzing more, I found that the problem is something else. Here is the scenario:

I have an ASP page say Base1.asp, this page has a link to a popup, when I click on this link a new window opens as a popoup say pop1.asp. The 'Save' on this popup calls the Stored Proc that performs some operation in the database. The operation that is performed in the database is a little time consuming (note that this SP is optimized enough). When I hit 'Save' on this popup, the SP is called, the database operation is performed and then this popup is closed and the parent page is refreshed with a parameter using window.opener.location in javascript. This process works fine most of the times.

When the multiple users say 5 use this functionality at the exactly same time, it has been found that the popup is not able to refresh the parent page. I see that the database opertaion is successful, the code of the popup gets executed successfully but the popup is not able to close itself and refresh the parent page. The popup just stayes on the screen. I could close it using the X on the top right of the window.

My questions:

1. Is there any other way to reload parent from the child window?
2. Are there any known problems with window.opener.location?

Also note that currently the code to refresh the parent and close the child is written in a javascript function which is called in the Onload event of the body tag.

1. Is this the right place to call this function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is just an individual page timing out I would add `Server.ScriptTimeout[=NumSeconds]` to the top of the offending page  as described in :-

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_scripttimeout.asp

Comment: script timeout is already set. Its happening on this page because it calls the SP that take some long time to execute.

Comment: Do you have an "on error resume next", simple IIS error messages or  whatever hiding your error messages?    http://powerasp.net/content/new/on-error-resume-next.asp

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions, first should the query take a long time? By reformulating it (adding an index or two) could it happen virtually instantly? Not being rude, but what do you mean by "heavy"? If not then I'd suggest you want to use an Ajax call to update the page when the query completes or fails. Its not difficult these days to do this, there are plenty of models out there.